# when sendOrderUpdateEmail function work?

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, order-email

I have `sendOrderUpdateEmail` in my module but this function, some times work and send email and some times,NOT.

I think this work if for example my prev. status was "**NEW**"

In which status, this function work and send update email to customers?

If I want to send update email for all status, how can I use this method in my module?

I used same as below in my module

```
$comment = $helper->__("Order status changed to: %s", $newState);
$order->setData('state', $status);
$order->setStatus($order->getConfig()->getStateDefaultStatus($status));
$history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment, false);
$history->setIsCustomerNotified(true);
$order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, $comment);
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

### The most probably it will not help, but check following.

Here is your function:

```
public function sendOrderUpdateEmail($notifyCustomer = true, $comment = '')
{
    $this->queueOrderUpdateEmail($notifyCustomer, $comment, true);
    return $this;
}
```

This function calls queueOrderUpdateEmail

```
/**
 * Queue email with order update information
 *
 * @param boolean $notifyCustomer
 * @param string $comment
 * @param bool $forceMode if true then email will be sent regardless of the fact that it was already sent previously
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
 */
public function queueOrderUpdateEmail($notifyCustomer = true, $comment = '', $forceMode = false)
```

In default magento this function calls with **forceMode** equals **true**. Maybe you have forceMode = false and according to description the letter will not send if it was sent by somehow.

Also you can try to put some `Mage::log` inside queueOrderUpdateEmail and determine why is it happening. If you need any help regarding this - just ask.

Comment: I think when we use `sendOrderUpdateEmail` then `forceMode` always is **true**, right?

Comment: If there no any rewrite.